# Base-64 Exception When Decoding id_token_hint Claims in Custom Policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am adapting [this email invite sample](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/invite/README.md) from the B2C Samples Github linked in the [define an ID token hint technical profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/id-token-hint) documentation for my purposes. I haven't made substantive changes to the policy itself, other than to add a token audience validation parameter. I have however adapted the token issuer to retrieve its certificate from Azure Key Vault.

The tokens generated contain signatures that are validating against [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/#debugger-io?token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IkI1NkFCNjI1RjE5NjBCQzk5NTZDNzhDMDVENTMzQjlDOEE1M0UzMUYiLCJ4NXQiOiJ0V3EySmZHV0M4bVZiSGpBWFZNN25JcFQ0eDgiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJuYW1lIjoiQm9iIFN1cnVuY2xlIiwiZW1haWwiOiJzcG9vZmVkLmluYm94QGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsInBob25lIjoiNTU1ODY3NTMwOSIsIm5iZiI6MTY4OTYxMTExNiwiZXhwIjoxNjg5Njk3NTE2LCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2xzbHNjdWIyY2FwcC5henVyZXdlYnNpdGVzLm5ldC8iLCJhdWQiOiJodHRwczovL2xzbGVhcm5iMmMuYjJjbG9naW4uY29tLyJ9.YQcTE4aAkMzs7_JHM-UJJHlfxSHzk0OnnzPB4vzHo4Of1In3v_lni9x7TpVTJQAq8lu33aygy9EwQyqY4L9eLNy4JVEXVFfMltd2jd4JZjxAHLqr4Ngb5EeuMM67ST_87MuBzWY4EKXR1X4ZJU8zsZv6_OCL57ycGzYr5FjEOd_Mojle8Pc3XjNYmRGTZqxt7LYqw-V0h6yjJoem0ui_9JodHMZr597leUN9Ki4oLPP-GUDpzw-n1F90dA1Rra1dZYTNFfUyGXolTmcSCSMWhC0BX_HSGu1kvGj_9aez1FyQuAlwTNMaG4dxPWii54lCzf77G6maMMA0c_IJDtHTHw&publicKey=%7B%0A%20%20%22e%22%3A%20%22AQAB%22%2C%0A%20%20%22kty%22%3A%20%22RSA%22%2C%0A%20%20%22n%22%3A%20%22sWUc8rBzx3u24caS15q7L8c-TFEQXVHufV2jwkdJGA_5s660PciYEQA-yuSlaXqln610AKbg1gdMLpUP_wQkAj5kmLltwJJww0TXovYi5pOqQJKru4QoFGiHWeyStC2_cokubRkW2RIvxK87nGcJVgP1JaYn1vGW9riYNLJg1pOTOPTRoiV7FPArtFt83Dr2iPN3sR2LTjDYFuUiGPpZwpQCqMV-gSeTRnqH6n0rUaVpmv8yOCpnwZ1JfLrHQkpRwsIxLo2MsfA0li3qOnb_I8k2iGjiGcImvW-qP5SskIMCl_NwPOE_xEMOBQdDSxqajRh7x2tmv1aWDonrUT1yUQ%22%0A%7D) (sample token validation included) using the [published metadata](https://lslscub2capp.azurewebsites.net/.well-known/openid-configuration) from the token issuer, so I'm at least relatively confident that the signed tokens are valid. However, I'm receiving an odd exception from the GetClaims orchestration step that processes the ID token hint:

> The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.

The message itself is somewhat concerning as everything in this exchange is Base64Url encoded and there are no padding characters in that encoding method. This appears to happen before any sort of token claim validation as I purposefully placed an incorrect value in the `<Item Key="IdTokenAudience" />` element of my technical profile to see how far the process got.

The last few bits of event output from Application Insights is reproduced below:

```
{
  "Kind": "Transition",
  "Content": {
    "EventName": "GetClaims",
    "StateName": "AwaitingNextStep"
  }
},
{
  "Kind": "Predicate",
  "Content": "Web.TPEngine.StateMachineHandlers.NoOpHandler"
},
{
  "Kind": "HandlerResult",
  "Content": {
    "Result": true,
    "Statebag": {
      "MACHSTATE": {
        "c": "2023-07-17T14:46:56.4499692Z",
        "k": "MACHSTATE",
        "v": "AwaitingNextStep",
        "p": true
      }
    },
    "PredicateResult": "True"
  }
},
{
  "Kind": "Action",
  "Content": "Web.TPEngine.StateMachineHandlers.GetRelyingPartyInputClaimsHandler"
},
{
  "Kind": "FatalException",
  "Content": {
    "Time": "2:46 PM",
    "Exception": {
      "Kind": "Handled",
      "HResult": "80131537",
      "Message": "The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters. ",
      "Data": {}
    }
  }
}
```

The technical profile hasn't been updated drastically from the sample other than to change the metadata endpoint and provide a token audience:

```
<ClaimsProvider>
  <DisplayName>My ID Token Hint ClaimsProvider</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="IdTokenHint_ExtractClaims">
      <DisplayName> My ID Token Hint TechnicalProfile</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="None" />
      <Metadata>
      
        <!--Sample action required: replace with your endpoint location -->
        <Item Key="METADATA">https://lslscub2capp.azurewebsites.net/.well-known/openid-configuration</Item>

        <Item Key="IdTokenAudience">https://lslearnb2c.b2clogin.com/</Item>
        <!-- <Item Key="issuer">your_optional_token_issuer_override</Item> -->
      </Metadata>
      <OutputClaims>
        <!--Sample: Read the email cliam from the id_token_hint-->
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />  
      </OutputClaims>
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
```

Comment: Is this a mismatch between one side expecting standard Base-64, while the other side is supplying URL-safe Base-64, or vice-versa?

Comment: @rossum As I don't have access to the internals of the B2C custom policy engine, I couldn't speak to that side of the equation, but the JWT and all elements of the metadata document are base64url encoded, seemingly properly if the "Signature Verified" output from jwt.io is any indication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a result of mistakenly encoding the `x5c` element of the JWKS document using base64url encoding rather than the [specified base64 encoding](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7517#section-4.7) required by the RFC.

(Beware the overly-helpful GitHub Copilot.)